# Get notified when database change Android

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, database, notifications

I have a SQL Server database and when there is insert in a table I want to notify the Android app.

For example, when order receives, I insert it into a SQL Server database. I also want user to get notification in my app about the order. The app is always open. I use web services to contact with database.

I don't want to request the table every 10 seconds or so. Is there any other way?

Comment: use push notifications.

Comment: Possibly, push notification is the best I can suggest.

Comment: Use push notifications

Comment: Thanks people ! will it notify my app about changes in db ? can you give me a good example link ?

Comment: here you go Full example enjoy  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I am using IIS(Windows) server and MS SQL database. And inserting from other android application, does it make any difference ? Can you give me example for those ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud messaging service, see how to set server [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html).

Example: if you are using PHP then while inserting or changing any data you can push to notify GCM to the given dives. or else you can set triggers in SQL and call system services to notify GCM.

Comment: I am using IIS(Windows) server and MS SQL database. And inserting from other android application, does it make any difference ? Can you give me example for those ?

Comment: ok, to connect to database you use web services, i guess asp.net or c# your case: you send request of order from device to server and server do some processing and then server insert it into a database.
so if you are using asp.net or c# see http://steveloper.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-and-asp-net/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434338/Android-GCM-Push-Notification

Comment: let me tell you to get notification to device you need device id and the message you want to send. what ever service or scripting language you are using just send a http request to gcm server with the given parameter and it will send your message to the device.