# How to get notified in an Android app when a new SQL Server record is inserted

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server in my Android app, and I want to send notification to the user whenever there is new message to his account, so is there a way I can get notified when a new row is inserted.

I saw people recommended triggers, but I don't how they are going to help me.

Comment: Either way you have to poll the database for changes. You can either poll the message table, or you can use a trigger to add an event to a queue and then poll the event queue. There is no magic way to detect and notify of change.

Comment: BTW we don't do "urgent" on this site. Pay a consultant if you have time restrictions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get notified when database change Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242438/get-notified-when-database-change-android)

Comment: @Dale k   , do you have a reference for that

Comment: @SamiiraMohamed a reference for what?